# How to save and load HTML5 Canvas to & from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, local-storage

I want the user to be able to save canvas drawings to the **localStorage** (using the Save button)under a custom name and then be able to load (using the load button) previous drawings from the localStorage.

Comment: Here's my canvas: http://jsfiddle.net/Eyf23/2

Comment: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/

Answer (score 11):

#### First option

If you want to save just a bitmap then you can save it this way:

```
localStorage.setItem(canvasName, canvas.toDataURL());
```

and then load like this:

```
var dataURL = localStorage.getItem(canvasName);
var img = new Image;
img.src = dataURL;
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
```

I recommend to use `canvas.toDataURL()` instead of `ctx.getImageData()` because `ctx.getImageData()` JSON string size will be just enormous even if canvas is empty.

#### Second option

If you want to store canvas as lines array then you should store lines coords in some variable and save it`s json:

```
localStorage.setItem(canvasName, JSON.stringify(linesArray));
```

Then you can load lines array and redraw canvas:

```
var lines = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(canvasName));
lines.forEach(function (line) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = line.color;
    ctx.moveTo(line.x1, line.y1);
    ctx.lineTo(line.x2, line.y2);
    ctx.stroke();
});
```

Comment: I used the toDataURL(). but I am getting an error "Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported".

Comment: @Sajith Most likely it's a security error. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22716873/2731099 – this answer may help you.

Answer (score 2):

First step will be to get image data from canvas.

```
var imageData = myCtxt.getImageData(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
```

Now store it to `localStorage` after `stringifying` it:

```
localStorage.setItem(savekey, JSON.stringify(idt));
```

To read and set the data back you can use following:

```
var idt = localStorage.getItem(savekey) || null;
if (idt !== null) {
    var data = JSON.parse(idt);
    ctx.putImageData(idt, 0, 0);
}
```

I have put the functions to handle the functionality in your <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eyf23/3/)</kbd>.

Regarding `localStorage` you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791569/specify-default-value-for-html5-local-storage-item) questions.