# How display a new image in a div, saved in local storage, each time the user re-visits the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Hard to explain in the title, let me explain.

I have 3 images and I would like them to be displayed in a div and rotate everytime a user re-visits the page (They will see one image when they visit, and a different image the next time).

I was thinking of having a variable like 'count' which increments each time the user visits, and the value of count would relate to which image is displayed in this div, however I'm not sure how to save the 3 images in the local storage.

I'm expecting the logic wpould be like

```
setItem (Img1)
setItem (Img2)
setItem (Img3)

count = count + 1

if count = 1
    div = getItem(Img1)
if count = 2
 etc etc
```

I guess my question is:

## Is there a way to store images in the local storage without first adding them to the page?

## EDIT

This is now the code I'm using, however an image is not displayed, the div just displays the image location.

```
var counter = localStorage.getItem('counter');
  if(counter == null) {
    localStorage.setItem("counter", 0);
    localStorage.setItem("images",'["assets/advert1.png","assets/advert2.png","assets/advert3.png"]');
    $('#advert').html(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images'))[0]);
  }
  else {
    $('#advert').html(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images'))[counter]);
    counter++;
    if(counter > 2) {
      counter = 0;
    }

    localStorage.setItem("counter", counter);
  }
```

(Note this is inside a document.ready function)

Comment: Why do you need to save the images to `localStorage`? Couldn't you have them in the dom as a `image` tag, and use the data you get back from `localStorage` to tell you which to show?

Comment: @Pytth I suppose I could, do you mean like hide them all and then have a count in local storage which defines which one to show?(Like if count = 1 img1.removeClass hide etc) Would you mind submitting a full answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible.

First, draw the image in a canvas:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

You can also download it directly from a link. Then save the canvas context into the local storage.

[How to save and load HTML5 Canvas to & from localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507534/how-to-save-and-load-html5-canvas-to-from-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use two variables, one to store an array of images and another to store the currently shown index.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var counter = localStorage.getItem('counter');
  if(counter == null)
  {
    localStorage.setItem("counter",0);
    localStorage.setItem("images",'["1.png","2.png","3.png"]');
    $('#displayArea').attr("src",JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images'))[0]);
  }
  else
  {
    $('#displayArea').attr("src",JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images'))[counter]);
    counter++;
    if(counter > 2)
    {
      counter = 0;
    }
    localStorage.setItem("counter",counter);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="displayArea"></img>
```

**UPDATE**

This code will produce an error in the stack snippet as it is a sandboxed environment. This snippet runs perfectly on a web page.

Comment: This return error
Error {
  "message": "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 16,
  "colno": 17
}

Comment: Yes it will return error here as it is a sandboxed environment , run it  on your page and check. If you gave me a downvote for this, its really your lack of knowledge..

Comment: This looks promising, I will try it out now and let you know how it goes. Thank you

Comment: Sure ask further if required

Comment: Hi @ShaktiPhartiyal I've added the code but unfortunatley it just displays the file location of the image inside the div (here's a screenshot: https://gyazo.com/41e9a8ab776ca1b904b2ee9b2ccc498b) I've updated my question with the code and was wondering if you wouldn't mind having a look at it, thanks very much.

Comment: Hi @EthanBristow Please check the updated answer in the answer the code `<img id="displayArea"></img>` should be you image. I hope you get it.

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal Thank you, I've tried that now but unfortunatley it still does the same, just displays the file location :/ my html is this <div id="product" class="unhidden">
                                <img id="advert">
                                </img>
                            </div> and in my JS i select ('#advert')

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` or [WebSQL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm) to deal with this problem

- Add image as a `Base64` then use counter 1,2,3 to choose which image to use
  but this will be using `JavaScript` so it will be loaded in Client-Side
- To convert image `Base64` you can use this [website](https://www.base64-image.de/)

You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page)

Answer (score 0):

Use random:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
```