# How to add null check for values returning from localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have a localStorage value, which I am getting

```
const marks = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('mark'))
```

Now I am trying to make it robust so that if there is no key with mark in localStorage then it should not break.

```
localstorage.getItem('mark') ? JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('mark')) : []
```

So is there any another way through which I can do the null check ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a Storage item is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262605/how-to-check-whether-a-storage-item-is-set)

Comment: Or maybe this question: [Specify default value for HTML5 Local Storage item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791569/specify-default-value-for-html5-local-storage-item).

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have provided? What characteristics does it lack that you're looking for? As is, your question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
localstorage.getItem('mark') === null ? [] : JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('mark'))
```

**EDIT**

Of course, It means:

```
if(localstorage.getItem('mark') === null){
 return '[]'
}else {
JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('mark'))
}
```

If item named mark is not null it will parse to JSON and u will get the result

Comment: Although this answer addresses the question, I would improve a lot if you could edit it and add an explanation on how that code helps

Comment: already edited, I hope the explanation can help you, is like you could either return null or an empty array

Comment: Your answer got listed in the low-quality review queue, I was suggesting how it could be improved ;-)